# OpenGL ES 2: VBO and Textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, vbo

My program does:

1. Load texture to GPU.
2. Load VBO of uv coordinates to GPU.
3. Load VBO of mode coordinates to GPU.
4. Load VBO of indeces to GPU.
5. Bind to texture.
6. Bind to uv coordinates VBO.
7. Bind to model coordinates VBO.
8. Bind to index coordiantes VBO.
9. DRAW

But only part of each texture is actually drawn. If I use all of the same arrays and draw without VBO's (move from client side each draw) it draws fine.....

Any ideas? Been scratching me head for a couple hours now.
I have posted relevant code below:

LOAD TO GPU:

```
    this.texture = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, this.texture, 0);

    //GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.texture[0]);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // Generate VBOs for UV data and model data. My indece VBO is done elswhere
    this.vbo = new int[2];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(2,vbo,0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo[0] );
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvsBuff.capacity() * FH_Utilities.SHORT_SIZE,
            uvsBuff, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuff.capacity() * FH_Utilities.SHORT_SIZE,
            posBuff, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

DRAWING:

GLES20.glUseProgram(this.terrainShader.mProgram);

```
    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(this.terrainShader.mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.texture[0]);
    int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (this.terrainShader.mProgram, "s_texture" );
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

    int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(this.terrainShader.mProgram, "a_texCoord");
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo[0]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2,
            GLES20.GL_SHORT, false,
            0, 0);

    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(this.terrainShader.mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo[1]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, 
            GLES20.GL_SHORT, false, 0, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.drawHandles[0][0]);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, this.drawHandles[0][1],     GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
```

GENERATE INDECES:

```
private int[][] genIndeces(int tileSize, int Nindexes){

        int[][] indeceHandles = new int[Nindexes][2];

        int         indMaxLen       = ((tileSize-1) * ((tileSize*2) +2))-2;
        int         indMaxBytes     = indMaxLen * FH_Utilities.SHORT_SIZE;
        short[][]   index           = new short[tileSize][tileSize];
        short[]     IDA             = new short[indMaxLen];
        ByteBuffer bInd;
        int nIndeces;
        int x,y;

        /* Build an Indece Buffer for course triangle strips */
        nIndeces = 0;
        for(y=0;y<tileSize;y++){
            for(x=0;x<tileSize;x++){
                index[y][x] = (short)nIndeces;
                nIndeces++;
            }
        }

        /*Run through however many resolutions desired */

        bInd = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indMaxBytes).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        ShortBuffer sInd = bInd.asShortBuffer();

        nIndeces=0;


        for(y=0;y<tileSize-1;y++){
            for(x=0;x<tileSize;x++){

                IDA[nIndeces] = index[y+1][x];
                nIndeces++;
                IDA[nIndeces] = index[y][x]; 
                nIndeces++;

                if(x==tileSize-1 && y != tileSize -2) { 
                    IDA[nIndeces] = index[y][x];
                    nIndeces++;
                    IDA[nIndeces] = index[y+2][0];
                    nIndeces++;
                }

            }
        }

        sInd.clear();
        sInd.put(IDA, 0, nIndeces);
        sInd.position(0);

        int tempHandle[] = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1,tempHandle,0);
        if(GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR){
            System.out.println("FH_ERROR- "+GLES20.glGetError());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, tempHandle[0]);
        if(GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR){
            System.out.println("FH_ERROR- "+GLES20.glGetError());
            System.exit(1);
        }  
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sInd.capacity() * FH_Utilities.SHORT_SIZE, sInd, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        if(GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR){
            System.out.println("FH_ERROR- "+GLES20.glGetError());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        if(GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR){
            System.out.println("FH_ERROR- "+GLES20.glGetError());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        indeceHandles[0][0] = tempHandle[0];
        indeceHandles[0][1] = nIndeces;



        bInd.limit(0);
        sInd.limit(0);
        bInd=null;
        sInd=null;
        IDA=null;
        index=null;
        System.gc();

        return indeceHandles;


    }
```

Comment: Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You're not showing the code that sets up the index buffer. I figure that's where the id and size are set in `drawHandles`? And your texture coordinates and positions are really of type `SHORT`?

Comment: @Reto: ya I am using shorts then displacing each tile with a translation matrix. I posted my indece generation above.